# Need help with Regular Expression for nine digit alphanumeric with minimum one space boundary

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match a [CUSIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSIP) number. I have the following, but it is missing some edge cases.

```
\s[A-Za-z0-9]{9}\s
```

I need to omit strings which contain a space in the middle and I need it to match strings which may be bordered by some other text. My strings are generally surrounded by tabs, but it may be as little as one space char separating the CUSIP from other text. Thanks in advance, I'm pretty green with regex. P.S. I'm working in .NET

Example

"[TAB]123456789[TAB]" should be matched (I'm getting this now)

"sometext[TAB]123456789[TAB]sometext" should be matched (this is not currently being returned)

"some text" should not be returned (I am currently getting this kind of match)

Comment: Do the "some text" type matches you're getting consist of 9-letter words such as 'alphabets' or 'puppydogs'?

Comment: How are you testing your matches? Because your regex looks OK, and I checked it with online regex tester (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and it matches your test strings correctly

Comment: @Sean U they could, but just as often they are strings with internal spaces. I was using http://regexpal.com/ to check the matches, and they were being included.

Comment: RegExr kicks regexpal's ass btw, thanks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page,](http://www.itsdoc.org/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=CUSIP) not just any 9-digit alphanumeric is a valid CUSIP.  The first three characters can only be digits, and the ninth is a checksum So if you want to distinguish CUSIPs from other 9-character strings, I believe this should work better:

```
\s[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\s
```

or, if you also want to match strings that are bordered by the beginning or end of input:

```
(^|\s)[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(\s|$)
```

or, if you also want to match strings that are bordered by punctuation (such as "(100ABCDEF)":

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)
```

I believe that should be a 99% solution, but if you want to be really robust you might also want to look into using the 9th (parity) character to verify that the strings are valid.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are wrong, not taking into account PPNs and allowing the check **digit** to be a letter. Therefore, here's a better solution.

Based on [this document](https://www.cusip.com/pdf/CUSIP_Intro_03.14.11.pdf) and [this document](https://www.cusip.com/pdf/CGS%20Private%20Placement%20Numbers.pdf), the CUSIPs have the following rules:

- Length is 9 characters.
- Characters 1, 2, 3 are **digits**.
- Characters 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 are either **letters or digits**.
- Characters 6, 7, 8 **can** also be *****, **@**, **#**.
- Character 9 is a check **digit**.

With this in mind, the following regex should provide a tight match:

```
^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9*@#]{3}[0-9]$
```

You can play around with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/nF7zZ7/2).

Note that this is as tight as possible without diving into too much details, which would turn the expression into a monster. I suggest you use the check digit algorithm to fully validate the CUSIP, which you can find [here](https://www.cusip.com/pdf/CUSIP_Intro_03.14.11.pdf).

Comment: This is great, but often the check digit is omitted in which case any of these solutions may fail to recognize a valid cusip. In my case, I simply made the check digit optional `^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9*@#]{3}[0-9]?$`

Answer (score 2):

```
string haystack = "some 123456789 text";//single space separators

string haystack2 = "some\t123456789\ttext";//tab separators

// The comment is correct, your pattern was correct originally.  
// This is just slightly dressed up.
string pattern = @"(\s+)(?<cusip>[A-Za-z0-9]{9})(\s+)";

Match m = Regex.Match(haystack, pattern);

Console.WriteLine("Match for cusip surrounded by spaces:" + m.Groups["cusip"]);
//Output: Match for cusip surrounded by spaces:123456789

Match m2 = Regex.Match(haystack2, pattern);

Console.WriteLine("Match for cusip surrounded by tabs:" + m2.Groups["cusip"]);
//Output: Match for cusip surrounded by tabs:123456789
```

Comment: This was very helpful as well but the below was an answer that also showed how my question could have been better. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Boolean CusipValidation(string sCusip)
    {
        string Cusippattern = @"^([0-9]){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]){6}$";

        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(sCusip, Cusippattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && sCusip != string.Empty)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```